# Help with qualitative research

Tags: research-process, methodology

Starting from the top, I am a student in Europe and I need to write a management project for my bacelour graduate work.

First everything was smooth, I chose appropriate topic, made a reasonable planning and started writing my proposal. Here the troubles began.
My tutor reccomended me to do a qualitative research, due to the small sample size. Honestly, I've never done qualitative research and now I am sooo lost in the Methods chapter.

My research design is explanatory (casual) as it aims to describe influence of one phenomenon on the other.The instrument of the research will be the interview due to persistance of my teacher at the qualitative research.

But could the explanatory design involve qualitative methods? Or shall I go for an other research design? If so, which one? 
Besides that, how do I choose the research methodology? I got a book of C. Dawson here and it lists some of these, such as action research,  entnography and grounded theory. But none of them suits here.... Are there more, which could be more suitable for explanatory research?

I am so lost in this, please help...

Comment: This question seems to broad and vague for this site as it is.  Can you make a specific, focused question here?

Comment: Also: I assume you asked this question to your tutor, what did he/she say?

Answer (score 3):

Qualitative research can be very important, but it is **crucial** to understand that qualitative research **cannot** establish causality. The only way to do that is with an experimental intervention or, if that is not possible, one of a number of quasi-experimental methods. The latter can be hard to find and even more difficult to analyze. For example, a court in the US invalidated laws prohibiting prostitution and it took the legislature two years to fix it, giving researchers a chance to look at the effect of the law on outcomes like violence against women or the spread of STDs.

If you have a small sample size, then none of the tools used to show causality may be feasible (especially for a BA project) and so you have to do something more exploratory.

Interviews can be important to understand how people think about a problem (if you want to help improve their decision-making process) or if you think certain beliefs/opinions are correlated with some behavior. However, you cannot establish causality with interviews, or any other qualitative method.